# slideDown for this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im new in the world of jQuery and Javascripts, so I want to ask you, how I can get an SlideDown for this Script:

```
// Focushandler
var current = null; //currently shown div

function focushandler(id) {
    if (current!==null) {
        current.style.display = 'none';
    }
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    div.style.display='block'
    current = div;
}

function clickhandler(e) {
    if (current == null){ //if both divs are hidden
        return;
    }
    e = e||window.event; //for IE8,7 compatibility
    var t = e.target || e.srcElement; // clicked element
    var sig = false;
    // now check all parents
    while (t) {
        if (t === current || t.nodeName == 'TEXTAREA') {
            sig = true;
        }
        t = t.parentNode;
    }
    if (sig) {
        return;
    }
    current.style.display='none';
    current = null;
}

if (document.documentElement.addEventListener) {
document.documentElement.addEventListener('click',clickhandler,false);
} else if (document.documentElement.attachEvent) {
    document.documentElement.attachEvent('onclick',clickhandler); //IE87
}
```

This code makes, that it shows an Div-Container when I'd click on a Textarea. When I click out, it hides. That works fine! But now I want, that it slide in when I focus the Textarea (.slideDown()). Can someone halp me? That would be really nice!

Answer (score 1):

The thing with the `JQuery` library, is that you don't need to wrote special code for every browser, it does it for you.

```
$("TEXTAREA").slideDown();
```

Comment: Where I have to fill it in?

Comment: And I want that the Box who is firstly hidden should going to slideDown, not the Textarea

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sphnix/qG4c3/). Hope helpful for you.

```
$(function(){
    $('#txtComments').on({
        'focus': function(){
            $('#commentTips').slideDown();
        },
        'blur': function(){
            $('#commentTips').slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```